# Delays browsing neo4j server

Tags: neo4j

I've installed Neo4J 3.2.1 server on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine with 16G of RAM. I'm connecting to this Neo4J server from my Windows 10 laptop via browser (http://server_ip_address:7474).

I'm working with 3 different graphs with 280MB, 6MB and 13MB. No problem when I activate one of the two smaller ones but impossible to work (make cypher queries in the NEO4J-browser) with the larger because it blocks for long periods (over one minute each).

I've tried to fix this myself. Read https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/ and set the following values in neo4j.conf file: - dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=12g; - dbms.memory.heap.max_size=12g; - dbms.memory.pagecache.size=4g.

I also tried: - echo noop > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler; - mount -o remount,noatime /.

Since none of these attempts worked, I would appreciate some help!

I'm not sure but it seems that there's some kind of cyclic script running causing the delays.

I only have trouble using the http browser server. I wrote a simple java application to make remote queries without using the http browser, produced a executable jar with it and when I run that jar and make the queries the response times are normal.

Comment: Can you share the queries you try?

Comment: It "stops" no matter what I try to do. Even to select a node/label from the database list. I'm able to do all cypher queries but with long delays to write, run and get the results.

Comment: What do you mean by "activating" a graph? Do you mean "creating a subgraph within the same DB"? Also, are you saying that even a simple request to get a single node from the "big graph" takes a long time (e.g., `MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n) = 123 RETURN n`, assuming 123 is the native ID of such a node)?

Comment: Have you tried to set JVM max memory manually in configuration? i.e.: `-Xmx 2048m`

Comment: @cybersam: The "active" database must be in the folder /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graphDb. Since I'm working with 3 different graphs (with 280MB, 6MB and 13MB) but can have only one available, what I do is to copy the graph I want to that folder. I only have delays when using the bigger one. Yes, even simple requests take a long time.

Comment: @Sergio La Rosa: I only have trouble using the http browser server. I wrote a simple java application to make remote queries without using the http browser, produced a executable jar with it and when I run that jar and make the queries the response times are normal (without any java heap size setting).

Comment: Well, viewing big graphs in browser make browsers crash easily, as far as I know; happened to me too with a graph of 100k nodes. 
I had to use `LIMIT` to avoid crashs and showing only small sections of the graph. Question: how many nodes has the 280mb graph?

Comment: @Sergio La Rosa: About 345000 nodes. Yes, I was expecting worst response times for the bigger graph but what I find strange are these kind of cyclic long delays and very reduced "time windows" between them to interact with the browser.

Comment: Can I ask you what browser are you using? I had "better" (somewhat) performance on Chrome; Firefox was very slow for me

Comment: @Sergio La Rosa: I'm using Chrome.